# Return value of commands when using stdin?

Tags: shell, shell-script, exit

Imaging I am executing the following command:

```
echo "root:mypass" | chpasswd
```

How can I get the return code / error code returned by chpasswd? Is that possible in this case at all? I tried

```
RET = `echo "root:mypass" | chpasswd`
```

but this gives me only "command not found"?

Comment: Be aware that every string passed as an argument to a command can be read by users using `ps`, or other means.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The $? variable holds the return value of the last command. You could do this:

```
echo "root:passwd" | chpasswd
RET=$?
```

Or test directly, e.g.

```
echo "root:passwd" | chpasswd
if [ "$?" -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "Failed"
fi
```

Comment: Thank you, that seems to work! Still wondering, if there is some kidn of "direct way" like in my example above?

Comment: No, but you can test on $? immediately afterwards without storing it in another variable if you don't need to keep it. Of course, if you run any other command it will update $? with its own result.

Answer (score 3):

If the return value isn't important, just if it succeeds or no, you can use the command within an `if` statement:

```
if ! echo "root:mypass" | chpasswd; then
  # chpasswd failed
fi
```

Or the shorter one:

```
echo "root:mypass" | chpasswd || cmd_to_run_if_chpasswd_failed
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand properly you're trying to change the pass of the root user using only an statement and pressing enter with no more confirmation of the process.

I found that your statement, runs properly if you add a "sudo su" prefix.

```
~$ sudo su
```

Considering that you're trying to change the pass of the root user, you must to know what is the root user name and to be logged properly. You can do this with the **sudo su** command.

Then its enough with runs the follow command replacing "root" with the current root name, and "my pass" with the desired password for this user (remember to take a note for try this method):

```
~$ echo "root:mypass" | chpasswd
```

After you can probe entering a **exit** command and **login** command using the new password.

Comment: You are not answering the OP's question, he was looking for a way to retrieve the return code for this command.